# SQL query mediawiki pages, order by creation date

Tags: mediawiki

I've been staring at the mediawiki database for my site.  I want to create a linear list of pages ordered by the original creation date of the page.

I can't find a timestamp anywhere that indicates the first creation date of the page.

I can find revision timestamps with no problem, in the revision table...but no original creation timestamp.  Furthermore, "page_touched" won't work since all these pages were xml imported recently, so they were all touched.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can't you just order them by `page_id`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the layout of the [`revision` table](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Revision_table). I did not test it, nor have seriously considered possible corner cases.

```
SELECT rev_page, rev_timestamp
FROM revision
WHERE rev_parent_id = 0
ORDER BY rev_timestamp
```

The first revision of a page has `rev_parent_id = 0`, so we take its timestamp as the creation timestamp.

Comment: I have a problem running this query in https://paws.wmflabs.org/ 
(it takes too much time)
And I can`t find dump for this table here
https://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/latest/